# Algorithm to solve $p(x)f''(x) + q(x)f(x) = 0$ where $p(x), q(x)$ are polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ordinary differential equation.

$$ p(x)f''(x) + q(x) f(x) = 0$$

Here, $p(x), q(x)$ are given polynomials in $x$. For example, in my physics education, I am interested in solving the following.

$$ 4x^2 f''(x) +(-15-8x^2-4x^4)f(x) = 0 $$

What are the general algorithms to solve these kind of differential equations? Any references are also very appreaciated. One of the ways that I know of would be assuming series solution and solve (recursively) for coefficients, but is there something else?

Comment: For linear equations of that type, one can frequently find power series solutions. The example you give has a regular singular point at $x_0=0$ so you should attempt it using the [method of Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks! As I mentioned in my answer I am aware of such a method. Have you by any chance heard of some other methods? Or maybe you know of some ODEs of this form which cannot be solved by series method?

Comment: I'm not thinking of  it now, but I believe there is a term for 2nd-order homogeneous linear ODE where the $f'$ term is missing.

Comment: As said above a power-series solution is usually what you want (and the best you often can get). However you can also often find integral representations and recursion formulas though this often requires very special forms of $p,q$. Don't think there is much general theory apart from Frobenius that covers all, but there is a lot of theory on special cases. You can take a look at the most common ones of this form: Bessel Function (the Bessel ODE for $Y= y\sqrt{x}$ has this form with $q = 1 - C/x^2$), Airy functions ($q = x$), Hermite functions ($q = 2n+1 - x^2$), ...

Comment: Some links: [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions), [Airy funtions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function), [Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions)

Answer (score 1):

There are difficult to have general algorithms, just solve it case by case.

Let $r=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{df}{dx}=\dfrac{df}{dr}\dfrac{dr}{dx}=2x\dfrac{df}{dr}$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(2x\dfrac{df}{dr}\right)=2x\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{df}{dr}\right)+2\dfrac{df}{dr}=2x\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\dfrac{df}{dr}\right)\dfrac{dr}{dx}+2\dfrac{df}{dr}=2x\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}2x+2\dfrac{df}{dr}=4x^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{df}{dr}=4r\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{df}{dr}$

$\therefore4r\left(4r\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+2\dfrac{df}{dr}\right)+(-15-8r-4r^2)f=0$

$16r^2\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+8r\dfrac{df}{dr}-(4r^2+8r+15)f=0$

Let $f=r^au$ ,

Then $\dfrac{df}{dr}=r^a\dfrac{du}{dr}+ar^{a-1}u$

$\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}=r^a\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+ar^{a-1}\dfrac{du}{dr}+ar^{a-1}\dfrac{du}{dr}+a(a-1)r^{a-2}u=r^a\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+2ar^{a-1}\dfrac{du}{dr}+a(a-1)r^{a-2}u$

$\therefore16r^2\left(r^a\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+2ar^{a-1}\dfrac{du}{dr}+a(a-1)r^{a-2}u\right)+8r\left(r^a\dfrac{du}{dr}+ar^{a-1}u\right)-(4r^2+8r+15)r^au=0$

$16r^2\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+32ar\dfrac{du}{dr}+16a(a-1)u+8r\dfrac{du}{dr}+8au-(4r^2+8r+15)u=0$

$16r^2\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+8(4a+1)r\dfrac{du}{dr}-(4r^2+8r-16a^2+8a+15)u=0$

Choose $-16a^2+8a+15=0$ , i.e. $a=\dfrac{5}{4}$ or $-\dfrac{3}{4}$ , the ODE becomes

$16r^2\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+48r\dfrac{du}{dr}-(4r^2+8r)u=0$ or $16r^2\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}-16r\dfrac{du}{dr}-(4r^2+8r)u=0$

$4r\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+12\dfrac{du}{dr}-(r+2)u=0$ or $4r\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}-4\dfrac{du}{dr}-(r+2)u=0$

The latter is simpler, since it has trivial particular solution $u=e^{-\frac{r}{2}}$

Let $u=e^{-\frac{r}{2}}v$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dr}=e^{-\frac{r}{2}}\dfrac{dv}{dr}-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{r}{2}}v}{2}$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}=e^{-\frac{r}{2}}\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{r}{2}}}{2}\dfrac{dv}{dr}-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{r}{2}}}{2}\dfrac{dv}{dr}+\dfrac{e^{-\frac{r}{2}}v}{4}=e^{-\frac{r}{2}}\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}-e^{-\frac{r}{2}}\dfrac{dv}{dr}+\dfrac{e^{-\frac{r}{2}}v}{4}$

$\therefore4r\left(e^{-\frac{r}{2}}\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}-e^{-\frac{r}{2}}\dfrac{dv}{dr}+\dfrac{e^{-\frac{r}{2}}v}{4}\right)-4\left(e^{-\frac{r}{2}}\dfrac{dv}{dr}-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{r}{2}}v}{2}\right)-(r+2)e^{-\frac{r}{2}}v=0$

$4r\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}-4r\dfrac{dv}{dr}+rv-4\dfrac{dv}{dr}+2v-(r+2)v=0$

$4r\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}-4(r+1)\dfrac{dv}{dr}=0$

$r\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}=(r+1)\dfrac{dv}{dr}$

$\dfrac{\dfrac{d^2v}{dr^2}}{\dfrac{dv}{dr}}=1+\dfrac{1}{r}$

$\ln\dfrac{dv}{dr}=r+\ln r+c$

$\dfrac{dv}{dr}=Cre^r$

$v=C_1(r-1)e^r+C_2$

$e^\frac{r}{2}u=C_1(r-1)e^r+C_2$

$r^\frac{3}{4}f=C_1(r-1)e^\frac{r}{2}+C_2e^{-\frac{r}{2}}$

$f=C_1(r-1)r^{-\frac{3}{4}}e^\frac{r}{2}+C_2r^{-\frac{3}{4}}e^{-\frac{r}{2}}$

$f=C_1(x^2-1)x^{-\frac{3}{2}}e^\frac{x^2}{2}+C_2x^{-\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Comment: OP gave that as an example, but specifically "What are the general algorithms to solve these kind of differential equations? Any references are also very appreaciated. One of the ways that I know of would be assuming series solution and solve (recursively) for coefficients, but is there something else?"

Comment: @doraemonpaul thanks, I really appreciate your detailed solution!